# Build JDocs without source

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, documentation, artifactory

I have an artificatory server (http://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) which I use to deploy certain 3rd party libraries to. I have a specific 3rd party library which has been provided along with a doc directory containing the JDocs for said library.

I would really like to compile the doc directory up into a jar so that I my team can drag down the JDocs (along with the 3rd party jar) from artifactory without having to distribute the doc directory independently. All of the tutorials I've googled for suggest that you have to have the source files to do this... which obviously, I don't have.

The things I've seen for maven suggest I need the source/project.

I've tried using `javadoc -d .\docs -source .\java\classes\library.jar -subpackage com.foobar` but it borks.

I've tried using Eclipse to Export the JDocs as an aggregated jar, but this is either not possible or I'm missing some runes.

Comment: You need the source files to generate the documentation, but you don't need them if you already have the docs, and you'd only need to run `javadoc` if you're generating them. I'm a little unclear on your specifics. Unless I'm misinterpreting your issue, all you need to do is take your existing third-party docs folder (or extract your third party docs JAR) and put it in your own docs folder, then include that folder in your JAR. Optionally you could have a separate JAR with just documentation in it, which plays nicely when adding libraries / docs to the build path in Eclipse.

Comment: That's what I'm after: A single JAR with the documentation in. How do I do that?
I've now tried zipping up the docs directory and renaming to match the binary artifact (with the "javadoc" suffix and .jar extension), and deployed it to Artifactory. Seems to work if I manually add it as the jdoc for the libriary, and it works. If I ask Maven to download the jdocs, it doesn't...
Sorry for being a blithering idiot... I know this is possible as my predecessor has previous versions of the library deployed with jdocs working... but I can't for the life of me work out how he did it.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your 3rd party javdoc dir structure looks like this

```
3rd-party-doc/
   +- index.html
   +- index-all.html
   +- ...
```

You can create a javadoc jar with following command

```
jar cvf 3rd-party-javadoc.jar -C 3rd-party-doc/ .
```

This generates the `3rd-party-javadoc.jar` which contains the javadoc which you could, for example install into your local maven repository.

**edit**
to install the generated javadoc into your local maven repository

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=3rd-party-javadoc.jar -DgroupId=com.example.3rd.party -DartifactId=3rd-party -Dversion=1.2.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dclassifier=javadoc -DcreateChecksum=true

# -Dfile=3rd-party-javadoc.jar - the javadoc file you have generated
# -DgroupId=com.example.3rd.party - the maven group id of the 3rd party library (same as in repository/.../3rd-party-x.y.z.pom)
# -DartifactId=3rd-party - the maven artifact id of the 3rd party library (same as in repository/.../3rd-party-x.y.z.pom)
# -Dversion=1.2.3 - the 3rd party library version (same as in repository/.../3rd-party-x.y.z.pom)
```

Comment: So this is good. I get my jar, and can deploy it in the same leaf as the binary jar for the library. However, when I ask Eclipse (via maven) to d/l the Javadocs, it blinks and does nothing. If I then ask to open the Javadocs for the dependency (i.e. right-click on the dependency, and click Maven->Open Javadoc) it opens the index.html correctly, but the IDE integration doesn't work. If I manually link a local copy of the javadoc archive to the Maven Dependency... it works. But this is a step I don't think I should have to do... or am I missing something?

Comment: How do you install the javadoc into your local maven repository? Or do you mean you deploy into a repository manager like Nexus?

Comment: I deployed it into a repository (Artifactory by JFrog). It does appear to download it, because my local maven repo has a copy of the file now... it's just the contextual help I'm used to (i.e. tied into javadocs) that I'm missing with this package.